# Голос народа и Глас народа - почему оба бронзовые?

Tags: обсуждение, знаки

> Голос народа - 15/30
>   Использовать 30 голосов в день
>
> Глас народа - 15/40
>   Использовать максимум 40 голосов в день

Вроде везде, где речь идёт об одном и том же действии, но в разном количестве, знаки имеют разный уровень, а тут - оба бронзовые - почему?

Comment: Отдельный вопрос, почему у нас два настолько близких названия? Чем голос и глас отличаются друг от друга?

Comment: @VladD: буквой «о». ) Надо бы переименовать один или оба. Но, судя по активности голосований за переводы, итоговый вариант мы примем как раз к новогодним каникулам.

Comment: Первый про использование *х* голосов, второй - про исчерпание максимума голосов.

Comment: связанный вопрос *[Предложение изменить название знака “голос народа”](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6613/191745)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

На англоязычном SO такая же ситуация: значки Suffrage и Vox Populi. На вопрос, зачем два значка, был дан [такой ответ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258763/4856258):

> Both badges are needed in order to encourage people to **vote for both questions and answers**; there was a tendency at one point for people to just vote for answers and leave the questions themselves a bit unloved. Since you can't vote for 40 answers in a single day (I think 30 is the maximum there) having the badge dangling there helps generate Good Behavior; it <s>tempts</s> nudges those people who are inveterate badge hunters to do the Right Thing without forcing them to do so.
>
> Which is the whole point of the badge system in the first place.

Многие люди голосуют только за ответы, а за вопросы не голосуют, а вопросам тоже нужны голоса. Чтобы немного стимулировать голосовать за вопросы, есть второй значок (голосуя только за ответы, его не получишь). На эту же тему, кстати, золотой знак [Электорат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate): требуется, чтобы не менее 25% от общего числа голосов были за вопросы. У знаменитого [Джона Скита](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity), например, этого значка нету: хотя он отдал почти 20000 голосов, только 19% из них за вопросы.

Ну а почему бронзовый - тоже понятно. Знак, который в принципе несложно накрутить себе за один день, не стоит делать серебряным.

Answer (score 7):

Наверное, серебряный знак это слишком жирно за то, чтобы 40 раз нажать кнопочку. Нормальные [серебряные знаки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=silver) получить гораздо сложнее, особенно такие как [эрудит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist), [гуру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru), [эпопея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic). Даже многие бронзовые знаки достаются сложнее.

Думаю, обе вехи были сделаны для того, чтобы простимулировать пользователей голосовать много, а потом ещё больше. Хотя бы раз. Голосование — полезное дело, ничего плохого не вижу в том, чтобы за него два значка дать.

Comment: честно говоря так оно и есть: для галочки (для значков) выполнил квест - убил почти целый день. Обычный день = 5-10 *k голосов (где k - некий личностный коэффициент; у меня он равен единице), плюс что-то идёт в избранное. Если возможно - то оставьте один бронзовый)

Comment: @Shilgen: изменить состав знаков не получится, т.к. это изменение может быть только в движке сайта и оно затронет все 140+ сайтов сети. Голосование — полезное дело, ничего плохого не вижу в том, чтобы за него два значка дать.

Answer (score 7):

Правильный ответ у @TagirValeev. Добавлю историческую справку.

Изначально был только один значок за 30 голосов, потом добавили второй за 40 голосов — после увеличения количества голосов в день, если голосуешь за вопросы. Старые значки обычно не удаляются (скажем, значок за прочтение FAQ уже нельзя получить, но он всё равно отображается), поэтому теперь значка два.

Если бы всё было реализовано изначально так, как сейчас, можно было бы обойтись одним значком. Стимулировать-то всё равно надо правильное поведение изначально, а не сначала "почти правильное", а потом "совсем правильное".

Comment: Не могу согласиться с тем, что тратить все голоса за день — это правильно. Вообще голосовать — хорошо и полезно. Но правил насчет количества нет. Наверняка, набивая этот значок, часть пользователей голосует гораздо менее разборчиво, чем обычно. Поэтому правильно — это голосовать за действительно хорошие сообщения, но никак не 40 раз в день.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Можно считерить и проголосовать за всё подряд, можно отсортировать вопросы по голосам и посмотреть, что на сайте популярного. При первом знакомстве с сайтом у меня совершенно естественным образом игногда получаются эти значки. Да и пусть даже юзер проголосует за всё подряд — у него хотя бы отложится в мозгу, что можно голосовать и за вопросы, и за ответы.

Comment: эх, а мне второй день подряд не хватает голосов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вполне может быть, что если голосовать за всё подряд вообще без разбора, то эти голоса система автоматически откатит при очередной проверке. Значок, конечно, останется при этом, но урона сообществу при этом не будет.