# Предложение изменить название знака "голос народа"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

В знаках есть два одинаковых наименования <kbd>Голос народа</kbd> и <kbd>Глас народа</kbd>:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Глас* - это синоним слова *голос*.
Знак <kbd>Голос народа</kbd> [на so именуется как](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)  <kbd>Suffrage</kbd>, что  может переводиться как *избирательное право*, *право голоса*, *голос*, *согласие*, *одобрение*, но не как *голос народа*.

Предложение изменить название метки *голос народа* на *избирательное право* или *право голоса* или предложите свой вариант.

Comment: Связанный [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1293/176217). Обратите внимание на первый комментарий.

Comment: *..судя по активности голосований за переводы, итоговый вариант мы примем как раз к новогодним каникулам..* @NickVolynkin как в воду глядел, только с годом ошибся )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Давайте изменим на *Активист*.

Comment: "Активист" только в голосовании? Как-то однобоко.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov «Голосист»?

Comment: @alexolut ответ только пошлый :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov это смотря как слово делить в уме ;)

Comment: @alexolut разумеется :) Я имел в виду "Николай Басков", а что вы имели в виду? :D

Answer (score 2):

Давайте не будем менять. Данное изменение излишне.

Comment: В словах и так сойдёт заложен негативный контекст, исправьте. Или мы подыгрываем некоторым вариантам?

Comment: @AK хорошо что еще картинку не вставил) поправил

Comment: Для картинки надо @Grundy приглашать

Answer (score -1):

Что если просто назвать "Активный"?

Comment: Или сразу «Активия» (можно даже с черносливом)

Answer (score -2):

Давайте изменим на *Активный гражданин*

Comment: https://ag.mos.ru

Comment: Не, я не из Москвы, я из России...

Answer (score -4):

Давайте изменим на *право голоса*

Answer (score -7):

Давайте изменим на *избирательное право*

Comment: думаю не совсем правильный в данном случае вариант, т.к. *избирать* больше ассоциируется с выборами