# голос за вопрос дает автору вопроса +n баллов репутации

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, справка

было произведено когда-то вот такое изменение:

[*Если кратко — с 14 ноября 2019 года голоса «за» приносят авторам вопросов не `5` баллов репутации как раньше, а `10`*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9753/178576)

а в справке до сих пор остаётся `5`:

[Голос за вопрос дает автору вопроса +5 баллов репутации.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

надо бы привести справку в соответствие с действительностью.

Comment: Никто не читает эти справки. А на самом деле тут нужен КМ, который куда-то пропал.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, как оказалось, кто-то всё-таки читает. иначе вопроса бы не было. а кто такой «КМ»?

Comment: КМ = Community Manager.

Comment: а ещё есть действующий КМ ?

Comment: @4per Конечно, у всех сообществ должен быть СМ я думаю ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Поправил.

Comment: Ещё опечатку бы поправить там же: "проголосовал «за» максимальн**Ы**е количество раз". И в некоторых местах `«за»` не очень удачно смотрятся, но это уже не так тривиально для исправления.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Спасибо. Готово! Пожалуйста, дайте знать, если надо будет еще что-то поправить!

Comment: "Голос народа" [теперь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6613/176217) "Активист". Может ещё сделать линки с картинок знаков на соответствующие страницы?